# Java Socket Communications Error

Tags: java, c++, sockets

On a high level, we are using **TCP** to communicate between two clients on a network. The clients are operating under different languages.

Our messaging workflow is as follows:

C++ initiates a command
Java reads the command
Java does some simple logic
Java responds

We have started to see more and more discrepancies with what the C++ code is sending, and what the Java code is receiving.
In order to track down this error, we have placed multiple logging statements and a **Wireshark** profile to attempt to capture as much data as possible to track the message.

C++ logs show that the command is being sent as "123,abc,def,456"

Debugging the C++ shows that the byte order of the characters matches this, as the command to write to the socket is being fired.

Wireshark shows the message coming through as "123,abc,def,456"

Java reads from the socket, and shows that the message is jumbled. We have gotten messages such as:

"123,abc,def,456" (correct)

"bc,def,456"(truncated)

"1a2,3bdfec,4,56"(completely mangled)

**Example of the C++ code**

```
while ( Client->Connected && !bolExitNow){ 
    data =S"";
    Threading::Thread::Sleep(15);
    bolReadStream = !bolReadStream;     
    if (!(bolReadStream && stream->DataAvailable )){
        if (sharedInfo->CutSocketClientPort == RemotePort){ 
                if (lbSocketMessages->read(&data)){ //the read() assigns stuff to data so that it's not an empty string anymore
                    bytes1 = Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes( data);
                        stream->Write( bytes1, 0, bytes1->Length );
                        if (sharedInfo->curAcknowledgeItem->SendMessageType->CompareTo(data->Substring(7,2)) == 0){
                            sharedInfo->LastXXMsgTime = DateTime::Now ;    
                        }
                    }
                    lbSocketMessages->acknowledge();
                    sharedInfo->WriteLog ( String::Format("{0} Sent msg: {1}",System::DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.fff"),data));//log write; This shows correct format message 
                }
        }
        continue;
    }
```

**Example of the java code**

```
/** Shared read buffer. */
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> buffer = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

    //Instantiation
    Socket client;
        try{
            client = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            sock[thread] = new SocketMagic(client);
            sock[thread].setMonitoring(false);
            sock[thread].setHeartbeat("");
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //Usage
    while (!done){
        if (socket[thread] != null && socket[thread].isAlive()){
            message = socket[thread].getLine(MAX_DELAY_INTERVAL);
            if(message!=null){
                logger.log("RECEIVING ON {" + thread + "}: " + message);//displays incorrect message data
                buffer.add(message);//Buffer for processing messages
            }
        }
        //...
        //logic
        //...
        if (buffer != null){
            message = buffer.poll();
            if (message != null){
                response = processMessage(message,thread);//obviously wrong, as we read in incorrect information above.
            }
        }
    }
```

SocketMagic library getline method is listed as

```
public String getLine()
    {
        return getLine(true, 0);//Always enable blocking
    }
public String getLine(final boolean blocking, final int maxwait)
        {
            // to block, or not to block (while waiting for data)
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            int character;
            boolean messageStarted = false;
            try
            {
                if (blocking)
                {
                    int wait = 0;
                    while (maxwait <= 0 || wait < maxwait)
                    {
                        while (sockIn.ready())
                        {
                            character = sockIn.read();
                            if (character == STX)
                            {
                                if (!messageStarted)
                                { // if no message started
                                    messageStarted = true; // start a message
                                } else
                                {
                                    buffer.setLength(0); // clear message buffer
                                }
                                continue; // don't add STX to buffer
                            }
                            // ignore characters prior to message start
                            if (!messageStarted)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            // if not end of message, keep reading
                            if (character != ETX)
                            {
                                // append to buffer
                                buffer.append((char) character);
                                continue;
                            }
                            // if the message is a heartbeat, keep reading
                            if (buffer.toString().equals(heartbeat))
                            {
                                buffer.setLength(0); // clear buffer
                                messageStarted = false;
                                continue;
                            }
                            // we've got a complete message, return it
                            return buffer.toString();
                        }
                        // sleep loop to avoid CPU wasting
                        try
                        {
                            wait += SLEEPSTEP;
                            Thread.sleep(SLEEPSTEP);
                            if (monitor && (wait % (HEARTBEATINTERVAL)) == 0)
                            {
                                if (!sockOut.write(heartbeat))
                                {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException ie)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } // ENDOF while ( !sock_in.ready() )
                } // ENDOF if (blocking)
                // set mark, if supported (which it should be)
                if (sockIn.markSupported())
                {
                    sockIn.mark(READAHEADSIZE);
                }
                while (sockIn.ready())
                {
                    character = sockIn.read();
                    if (character == STX)
                    {
                        if (!messageStarted)
                        { // if no message started
                            messageStarted = true; // start a message
                        } else
                        {
                            buffer.setLength(0); // clear message buffer
                        }
                        continue; // don't add STX to buffer
                    }
                    // ignore characters prior to message start
                    if (!messageStarted)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if not end of message, keep reading
                    if (character != ETX)
                    {
                        buffer.append((char) character); // add char to buffer
                        continue;
                    }
                    // if we read a heartbeat message, keep reading
                    if (buffer.toString().equals(heartbeat))
                    {
                        // System.out.println("DEBUG: HEARTBEAT");
                        buffer.setLength(0);
                        messageStarted = false;
                        // set new mark position for input stream
                        if (sockIn.markSupported())
                        {
                            sockIn.mark(READAHEADSIZE);
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    // we've got a complete message, mission accomplished!
                    // return buffer.substring(1, buffer.length() - 1);
                    return buffer.toString();
                } // ENDOF while (sockIn.ready())
                // incomplete message, reset the mark, if supported
                if (sockIn.markSupported())
                {
                    sockIn.reset();
                }
                return null; // no message or incomplete message
            } catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                return null;
            }
        } // ENDOF public String getLine(boolean blocking, int maxwait)
```

Comment: What is `SocketMagic`?  I assume it's `SocketMagic.getLine()` that is actually doing the reading?

Comment: What is `SocketMagic.getLine()`? How can you possibly expect to get help about code you haven't posted?

Comment: That seems to be the default socket library, Apologies; I don't have access to the source for that.

Comment: No it is not. It is something you have either written or imported as a third-party library.

Comment: I've just Googled "java SocketMagic" and got nothing.

Comment: I'm looking for the source now, Edit will be incoming within a few minutes.

Comment: That's not the right code (or all the code): you're calling `getLine(MAX_DELAY_INTERVAL)`, but the method you posted has two parameters.

Comment: I think the only way you're going to be able to fix this is by stepping through the code.

Comment: I've attempted to step through most of the code-- The issue only crops up intermittently, my testing in the last day or so I haven't seen it, no code changes since the last time it cropped up, so I haven't been able to step through the issue in the debugger.

Comment: BTW, you only want to catch errors if you can do something about it.  There's no point catching something like an IOException on the socket creation, and then allowing the program to continue and try and read from the socket.

Comment: There was some data there that I felt was against our corporate policy to post, so the catch statements are filler, for the most part.

Comment: This code is rubbish. It has a `blocking` option that causes nothing whatsoever to happen if it isn't `true`. It doesn't read lines, but messages. It requires messages to start with STX and end with ETX - are you sending those? It doesn't have any escape handling for messages with embedded STX or ETX.